# Expresscache doesn't show information or statistics

Tags: windows-8, ssd, hard-drive-cache

After installing Expresscache from scratch on a Samsung Series 5 Ultra (NP530U3C), I ran `eccmd -partition 1` (as drive 1 is the ssd) and I can confirm that there is a new partition created. However `eccmd -info` shows absolutely nothing besides copyright information and the current date.

```
C:\Program Files\Condusiv Technologies\ExpressCache>ECCmd -info
ExpressCache Command Version 1.0.94.0 Copyright® 2010-2012 Condusiv
Technologies. Date Time: 7/13/2014 0:22:50:404 (HERBERT #0)
```

This is running on a laptop with 64bit Windows 8. I guess expresscache isn't properly configured, but neither does rebooting change anything nor does `eccmd -preload "C:\Program Files"` seem to have any effect. How do I enable this software properly?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem that i solved some days back. (i have seen your query while searching for info and coming back as I have found the solution, at least which worked for me..)

it seems that the intel rapid storage technology driver (IRST) version you have is not really compatible with the version of express cache software that you just installed.

(in my case my pc was initially a windows 8 pre installed one and i had updated it to windows 8.1, I had IRST driver in a folder of my asus laptop - the folder name was Vista64_Win7_64_Win8_64_11.5.0.1207 
and a folder with express cache named - Win8_64_1.0.86
-notice the version info.)

that being said,

The latest express cache version that asus provided me when i went to their support website was - ExpressCashe_Win8_64_VER10100 
and the latest IRST that i could download from their site was - IRST_Intel_Win7_8_64_Z11701013 - notice that they have proposed those for windows 8.  )

It didn't work for me as my express cache info was empty.

what i did was simple, I've uninstalled IRST and express cache,restarted, cleaned my registry, and installed the latest intel driver with the older version of express cache "et voila" it worked like a "merveille"!  :)

hope that might help?!
ps: mark as answer if it works for you!

wish you alot of sun, ciao